# Submit batch entry in datatables.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using ASP.Net webform for my development and currently implement datatables.net. to perform some excel like data entry job. For more info, please go to http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/KeyTable/editing.html. I also added some add row and delete row functions at client side. Now I am stuck on how to push the entire table data to the server. It's look like excel and user can make the amendment. Whenever they plan to save the data, the user just need to click on save button and the entire table info shall be submitted to the server. For your information, no input textbox in this case because I am using keytable feature.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [datatables.net server side usage page](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) has **sServerMethod** which may be fullfill your requirement. The data are passing in JSON format to server. In server side you can parse the JSON back to your DTO to update your data.

Comment: Hi. the example shown looks like getting data from the server with post method. Would you mind show me a simple code in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can SqlBulkCopy for faster insertion of data in the database. You can search code for that on net.

Comment: Hi vishal, My main concern is how to push the data from datatables.net to server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an object collection of some kind in your handler to temporarily save the data into some kind of structure or object. What I did was append a row_id to the table row in the fnRowCallback of the Datatable, then grabbed it in the submitdata property of the Editable plugin, sending it to the server. Once there, I store it in an object, add it to the collection, and let editable update the table.

When you are ready to submit, fire it off, go to the handler, and send all of the data in the collection to the server as a mass update.

Comment: Hi jlrolin. Thanks for your reply. Personally I solved it by store the information as hidden field dynamically.